# Populating a spinner with a db query

Tags: android, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I recently started programming for android and java development in general. Currently I train by writing a timetable app.
I want to get  a list with all subjects from the db (the table also contains teacher and rooms) and put them into a spinner.
Thats the code I wrote

```
Cursor c = dba.fetchAllSubjects();

if (c.getCount() != 0)  {
    Spinner subjectSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.newlesson_subject);
    startManagingCursor(c);
    String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_SUBJECT}; 
    int[] to = new int[] {android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item};
    SimpleCursorAdapter subjectAdapter = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to);
    subjectSpinner.setAdapter(subjectAdapter);
}
```

The problem is that when clicking on the spinner it shows a list  with as much items as the db has entries, but the list doesn't show the names (you can say it's empty). So I probably messed something up with the simple cursor adapter, but I don't know what.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're error lies in specifying the wrong Resource ID in your **to** integer array.

```
int[] to = new int[] {android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item};
```

You need to specify the ID of a TextView (or similarly typed view) and not the layout itself. Replace the line above with:

```
int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
```